# Why does NuGet check out all csproj-files in TFS on update-package?

Tags: tfs, nuget

I have a solution with multiple projects, many of the projects have NuGet packages installed, some of them have the same packages installed. When I run `update-package` NuGet checks out every csproj-file and occasioanlly it also adds some app.config file to some projects.

Answer (score 0):

Did those projects actually get updated? If so then the csproj file will get updated. app/web.config gets added if a package adds it or if you need binding redirects for the packages to work together.

Comment: No, the projects weren't updated. And regarding the app.config it isn't needed by any of the projects.

Comment: Does it repro for all solutions you use nuget with?

Comment: It happens for all our solution, I think we have three of them. How does NuGet the update? Does it opens the csproj-file with read and write? That might be the issue if that is the case since I guess TFS will se a change and checkout the csproj-file if so.

Comment: No it does not. Update isn't related to a csproj file. When things change in your project, your project file will update as a result. I'd  try to slim your repro down to one solution with one project under tfs, install an old package then update it. That will update the csproj file if for example the assembly reference changes. Are you sure there are no valid changes in the csproj?

Comment: Yes I am sure that there are no valid changes. I can check all and do a "Undo checkout" and VS will undo all the files except those that has changed.